# Sending email using Gradle

Tags: gradle, task

I have written a task (actually copied from Internet), it sends email to given email. But when I run it, I get  `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage` exception. I have included `compile group: 'javax.mail', name: 'javax.mail-api', version: '1.5.1'` in dependencies but still getting this. Here is the task

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

class MailSender extends DefaultTask {

    @TaskAction
    def sendMail(){
        def mailParams = [
                mailhost: "smtp.gmail.com",
                mailport:"465",
                subject: "Email Recieved",
                messagemimetype: "text/plain",
                user: "allaudinqazi@gmail.com",
                password:"", // 
                enableStartTLS:"true",
                ssl:"true"
        ]
        ant.mail (mailParams) {
            from (address:'allaudinqazi@gmail.com')
            to (address:'allaudinqazi@gmail.com')
        }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "uk.org.sportscotland.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.1.1"
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-1.7.0.jar')
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'
    compile group: 'javax.mail', name: 'javax.mail-api', version: '1.5.1'
}

ext {
    fileName = "SSV01"
}

task copyToDropbox(type: Copy){
    from "build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk"
    into "F:/folder/Dropbox/Builds/SS"
    rename {
        fileName + ".apk"
    }
}

task mail(type: MailSender){}
```

Comment: Provide full build script.

Comment: I have updated code. Please have a look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have incorrectly added `javax.mail` to the `compile` configuration. Since this is needed at build time you will need to add it to the `buildscript` dependencies.

Eg:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'javax.mail:javax.mail-api:1.5.1'
    }
}
```

More info [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html#sec:external_dependencies)

Comment: it says, could not find javax:javax.mail-api:1.5.1

Comment: You'll also need to declare one or more repositories

Comment: buildscript { repositories { jcenter() } dependencies { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0' classpath 'javax:javax.mail-api:1.5.1' }

Comment: it didn't fix for me. any other suggestion ?

Answer (score 2):

Reading the docs for the [mail task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/mail.html) it says

> Note: This task may depend on external libraries that are not included in the Ant distribution. See Library Dependencies for more information.

I seem to remember that ant was a bit wierd like this and expected you to drop jar files into %ANT_HOME%/lib. So, I think the mail task will need to be loaded by the same classloader as the mail/activation jars. To me that means two options:

1. Add jars to ant's classloader as specified [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-send-email-by-using-ant-mail/6593/2). This approach feels very hacky to me and will likely break in Java 9 when URLClassloader is NOT guaranteed.
2. Use `ant.taskdef` to define another mail task (eg `mail2`) with all the required jars in the classpath. This would be my preferred approach.

Eg:

```
configurations { antMail }
dependencies {
   antMail 'ant:ant-javamail:1.6.5'
   antMail 'javax.activation:activation:1.1.1'
   antMail 'javax.mail:mail:1.4.7'
}
ant.taskdef(
    name: 'mail2',
    classname: 'org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.email.EmailTask',
    classpath: configurations.antMail.asPath
)
ant.mail2(mailParams) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems groupId change by the time (javax >> javax.mail):
You need to replace by:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'javax.mail:javax.mail-api:1.5.6'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to put

```
classpath 'javax.mail:javax.mail-api:1.5.5'
```

in your buildscript dependencies