# Perform some high-level operation of Unit test finish?

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle, automation, automated-tests

Is it possible to perform some high-level operation at Unit testing end?

Like grabbing all test results and logs and sending them by email to developer?

Would like solution either in JUnit or with Gradle.

Answer (score 1):

A pure `JUnit` approach could be to implement your own [`RunListener`](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html) to be able to grab the information of each of your tests.

To invoke your listener, you need to run your tests through `JUnitCore`.

```
 public void main(String... args) {
    JUnitCore core= new JUnitCore();
    core.addListener(new MyRunListener());
    core.run(MyTestClass.class);
 }
```

A pure `Gradle` approach could be to implement your own [`TestListener`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/TestListener.html) to be able to grab the information of each of your tests and send the final report.

In `build.gradle` you will need to add `gradle.addListener(new my.package.MyTestListener())`. Your listener must be in the build source directory also known as `buildSrc`.

Answer (score 1):

```
test.finalizedBy(someHighLevelOperationTask)
```

Example: Here is a task that you can call `gradle emailTestResults` that would depend on `'zipTestResults'` which depends on `test`. I have not done the email part of it, there's a question that covers that: [Sending email using Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37293194/sending-email-using-gradle)

So this just spits out a `println` in place of the email task:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

task zipTestResults(dependsOn: 'test', type: Zip){
    from 'build/reports/tests'
    baseName 'TestReport'
    destinationDir file('build/reports')
}

task emailTestResults(dependsOn: 'zipTestResults') << {
  println 'Emailing...' + file('build/reports/TestReport.zip')
}

repositories{
    jcenter()
}

dependencies{
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

But that won't work if the test fails, so, there maybe a better way, but you can add this:

```
test.ignoreFailures = true
```

Then if you then always want to email the test results add:

```
test.finalizedBy(emailTestResults)
```

Then a `gradle test` would finish by emailing the results.